# testing for existance of a row in a table using mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Ive written the following method to test whether a user with username $uname exists in a mysql database. unfortunately it returns no rows, even in cases where the user definately exists. im presuming there is a complication because its a prepared statement but im not sure how/

```
public function isUserExists($uname)
 {
    $b = false;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE `username` = ?";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$uname);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
echo "num rows:  ".$stmt->num_rows;
    if($stmt->num_rows >= 1)
    {
        echo "user already exists"."<br />";
        $b = true;
    }
    return $b; 
 }
```

Comment: Try adding `$stmt->store_result();` after the `execute` but before you use `num_rows`.

Comment: Did that fix it? If so, I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to retrieve the result after executing the query in order to work with the results. Add `$stmt->store_result();` after the `execute` but before you use `num_rows`.